# Object Reference Error - Show class name with error?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

When I get an Object Ref error, it can sometimes be a real pain to find out which variable is causing the error (when you can't debug). Is there a way for this error to throw the classname that isn't assigned?

So: I want the name of the type of the variable that was unexpectedly null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The class name of what, exactly? Sounds like you want the name of the type of the variable that was unexpectedly null. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its only the information in the stack trace which would be the first step in finding out where the error has originated. Also you should make sure you check the complete stack trace (all inner exceptions too). This would give you the method name with complete namespace. So that should be fairly good step to see where the error is, unless the standard coding is really bad.

Comment: If a method is using quite a few different classes then there are multiple places that an error like this could be raised. This is the issue I face sometimes. Another example is when you are missing a control on a ascx page and reference it in the code behind, it can be a pain to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can get the class name, the closes I get is to get the class and method name, then the stack trace:

```
try
    {

    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        xxx.API.ErrorHandler.Handler.HandleError( ex, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName );
    }
```

Comment: The stack trace already provided the Class and Method name doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah it is, but my hander takes the class and method name as parameters as this is easier to pass with reflection rather than trying to read the stack trace